# Android Studio with Firebase Not Working

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I'm trying to make a messenger Using Firebase.

And then android studio gives me an error.
 Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Here's the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\***\AndroidStudioProjects\TheMessenger\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\***\AndroidStudioProjects\TheMessenger\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/firebase/client/AuthData;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Here's My Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "joel.themessenger"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.1.2+'
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
}

Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://intense-inferno-9606.firebaseio.com/");
EditText messageInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
String message;
String name = "Joël";

public void sendMessage(View v) {
    message = messageInput.getText().toString();
    Map<String, String> post = new HashMap<String, String>();
    post.put("name", name);
    post.put("text", message);
    myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(post);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I Saved The Jar file in the folder app/libs/firebase-client-android-2.1.2.jar

I got the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the Android-Manifest.

Thanks in Advance!

Solution:

I included `com.firebase.client.AuthData` twice, I had to delete the jar file and the dependencies in my build.gradle is enough. But now i get another error!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joel.themessenger/joel.themessenger.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.
```

While i instantiated it in my mainactivity. Any help?

I had to use `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` somewhere else. You'll have to create a new java file that will look somethig like this

```
 import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

    public class MessengerApplication extends android.app.Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        }
    }
```

Then you'll have to edit the androidManifest. You'll have to add `android:name="<Your_Package_Name>.<JavaFile>"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error means that you've included the `com.firebase.client.AuthData` class in your project twice, which you're not permitted to do. By your description one copy is coming from:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.1.2+'
```

and the other is from:

> I Saved The Jar file in the folder app/libs/firebase-client-android-2.1.2.jar

I would recommend removing the jar from your libs folder and just using the statement in your build script; that makes it easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks now i haven't got the error anymore but i get another :(    `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joel.themessenger/joel.themessenger.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: You need to set the Android context using Firebase.setAndroidContext() before using Firebase.` But i did use Firebase.setAndroidContext()  in my mainactivity or is this done wrong?

Comment: The error message seems to explain pretty clearly what you should do.

Comment: Yes, but i already used Firebase.setAndroidContext (this);  but it still gives me errors

Comment: I got it working! It seems that i used setandroidcontext() wrong i had to create a new java file and do it there.